# Return a sublist from a nested list if it partially matches a sublist from another nested list

Tags: python

I have a list of word frequencies in English, which includes the word, its part of speech (POS) and its frequency, in a nested list

```
freq_list = 
[['such', 'JJ', '17930'],
['year', 'NN', '17920'],
['as', 'RB', '17107']]
```

I also have a nested list of tokens which comprises the word and POS.

```
tokens = 
[['legend', 'NN'], 
['of', 'IN'], 
['zelda', 'NN']]
```

I want to compare the lists, and if the word and POS from tokens is in freq_list, I want to append the last value in the freq_list to the token.

```
    def get_frequency(self, tokens, freq_list):
            self.__frequencies = []
            for token in self.tokens:
                if token[0] in [item[0] for item in self.freq_list] and 
    token[1] in [item[1] for item in self.freq_list]]:
                    freq = token, self.freq_list(i)
```

I'm struggling with the last line, which defines freq. I want it to be the word and POS from tokens (or from freq_list, they should be the same) and the corresponding frequency from freq_list. Any suggestions would be great.

Also, I need to use if statements, because there will be two other conditions to be met (e.g. if token[0] in self.freq_list and if neither token[0] nor token[1] are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off modeling this with a dictionary rather than nested lists:

```
freqs = {}
for word, pos, f in freq_list:
    if word not in freqs: freqs[word] = {}
    freqs[word][pos] = f

for i, (word, pos) in enumerate(tokens):
    if word not in freqs:
        tokens[i].append(0)  # fix for scenario #2
        continue
    if pos not in freqs[word]:  # fix for scenario #1
        pos = "UNK"
        if pos not in freqs[word]: continue
        tokens[i].append(freqs[word][pos])
        continue
    tokens[i].append(freqs[word][pos])
```

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you. I can now get the frequency if the word and pos are in the list. 

One issue is that I want to account for two other scenarios:

1) the word is in the list, but with a different pos (the frequency list is very flawed, and there are 10,000+ words that are marked UNK for unknown. In this scenario, I want to also take the word frequency

2) neither the word, not the frequency are in the list, in which case I want to append 0 (this is because I will eventually calculate the mean word frequency and don't want to have missing values)

Comment: this works really well, except when I go to get the mean word frequency, I notice that the length of some of the lists in 2, instead of 3. I'm a bit stumped by this, maybe it's because I'm using the function recursively? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: It seems that the issue is that there are a lot of words which are incorrectly tagged by the nltk tagger, e.g. silent is tagged as a noun. The frequency list doesn't have an entry for silent as a noun, so when I try to append the frequency, it gives a key error.

Comment: @jan: I understand the issue. How would you like to fix it? I can write the code (you probably could, too), but the design fix has to come from you

Comment: @jan: I think you need to make a new post, as code formatting is lost in comments. I'll pitch in when I see the post :)

Comment: after inspecting the data, I decided that the most common freq_list value is almost always right, so I decided to skip the POS and just append that. I changed the code to this, but now it appends every value for that word.
```
for i, (word, pos) in enumerate(tokens):if word not in freqs: 
    tokens[i].append(0)
        continue
    if pos not in freqs[word]:
        tokens[i] = [tokens[i][0:2]]
        single_token = tokens[i][0]
        if single_token[0] in freqs:
            tokens[i].append(freqs[word].values())
        continue
tokens[i].append(freqs[word][pos])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the two lists, check for the match and append the third item to the other list:

Normal looping:

```
for x in tokens:
    for y in freq_list:
        if x == y[:2]:
            x.append(y[2])
```